# Android Gradle build-info.xml not found

Tags: android, gradle

When i try to start an old App with the InstantRun it says that:

Gradle build-info.xml not found for module app. Please make sure that you are using gradle plugin '2.0.0-alpha4' or higher.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the recent release of Android Studio 2.0, there is a new Android gradle plugin 2.0.0.  You can apply that in your top-level build.gradle buildscript block by changing the version of the plugin to look like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
    }
}
```

EDIT: Some projects that were previously managed by Android Studio 1.5 may exhibit strange problems like this.  To clear these problems, it may be required to delete the project's `.idea` directory and re-import it into AS 2.0.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Make sure you're using the full version of Android Studio 2.0 and not some prior alpha or beta release.  This is all working just fine for me with the fully released version from yesterday.

Comment: I have performed a clean reainstall. It doesn't work only with a project created with Android studio 1.5

Comment: I successfully loaded my old projects from AS 1.5.  All I had to do was change the gradle plugin version as shown in the answer.

Comment: I've already changed it. I don't know what to do. Tomorrow I'll try to paste the classes in a new project

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is deleting the .idea directory of the project and re-import the whole thing as a gradle project.

Comment: deleting .idea folder and importing it worked for me in Android Studio 2.1.1 with Gradle Plugin 2.1.0

Answer (score 4):

It happend after updated to Studio 2.0, 
I disable Instant Run function fix this issue

**Update**

After I upgrade android studio to version 2.1.1, enable instant run function. it works

**Update2**

It seems when I build release version, enable instant run is OK, not for debug version build. so strange.